# submitting different ajax loaded with the same custom submit button

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

So it's kind of complicated what I'm trying to do. So let me give an example of code i got working first: {[im using jquery rotate plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)}

```
$("#img").rotate({ 
    bind: 
      { 
         click: function(){
           postlogic();
           $(this).rotate({ angle:0,animateTo:-360,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo });
         }
     } 

});

function submitlogic(){
    // ---------------- post cache ----------------//
    var firstpost = $("#form_1").serialize();
    var secondpost = $("#form_2").serialize();

    // ------------ post logic -----------------//              
    if(pagetrack = 1){
        $.post('query1.php',firstpost,function(data) { 
            $("#new_content_here").html(data);
        });
        var pagetrack = 2;
    } else if(pagetrack = 2){
        $.post('query2.php',secondpost,function(data) { 
            $("#new_content_here").html(data);
        });
        var pagetrack = 3;   
    }
}
```

Basically I want this image to be my submit button. This image-button will always be on the page and have the same behavior. I have some options to post, the user hits my rotating button, the options are submit to the database, and new options are displayed and the user then proceeds to select from these. "Pagetrack" tracks which form I'm on.

My problem is that after I submit the first time, I can't get the submit to work again. There's probably some big concept I'm missing, but I don't know what it is. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: what are you looking for? the server code or after its echoed through? after its echoed through its just a bunch of radio buttons in divs in a form. the only attribute my form tag has is an id.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yoshim/QaZBM/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QaZBM/2/ i divided up the menus cause the spacing was weird

Comment: I dont see #form_2, where is it? why you are hidding all the fields?

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare your `pagetrack` variable outside `submitlogic` function so the state will stay between function calls.

```
var pagetrack = 1;
function submitlogic(){
    // ---------------- post cache ----------------//
    var firstpost = $("#form_1").serialize();
    var secondpost = $("#form_2").serialize();

    // ------------ post logic -----------------//              
    if(pagetrack = 1){
        $.post('query1.php',firstpost,function(data) { 
            $("#new_content_here").html(data);
        });
        pagetrack = 2;
    } else if(pagetrack = 2){
        $.post('query2.php',secondpost,function(data) { 
            $("#new_content_here").html(data);
        });
        // if you have only two elements you should use pagetrack = 1; here
        pagetrack = 3;   
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, i tried this, it didn't work. it looks like my values are submitting (the selected radio buttons disappear); but my image isnt rotating and the second post still isnt showing up

Comment: i think the problem is that the value of pagetrack isn't being set globally, something is wrong with my scope, but i can't figure it out. i thought this might work, but it didn't

Comment: i figured it out -- the var needs to be taken off pagetrack -- it closes the scope on the variable. im still having problems with the image rotating now. it submits when i click image, but it still doesn't rotate.